# Let $x,y>1$ be coprime integers and $g>0$ a real number such that $g^x,g^y$ are both integers. Is it true that $g\in\mathbb N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization, integer-lattices

Let:

- $x, y\ $ be coprime integers greater than $1$
- $g \in \mathbb{R}^+$
- $g_,^x \ g^y \in \mathbb{N}$

**Proposition:** $g \in \mathbb{N}$

I have not managed to prove it. Via the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, I have proved (at least I believe so) that if $g$ is rational, it is an integer. However, I am not sure about the case of irrational $g$; I believe such irrational $g$ can exist. **Can anyone (dis-)prove this?**

---

My intuition behind it is this (I'm only using $x$ but the same applies to $y$): for $g^x$ to be integer, $g$ must be the $x^\text{th}$ root of $r_x = g^x$, i.e. $g = \sqrt[x]{r_x}$. We can construct the divisor lattice of $r_x$ and its *"divisor cuboid"*: a generalized Hasse diagram of divisors of $r_x$, in wich the divisors are equally spaced, and which is continuous, viz. there are real numbers between the integer divisors. Now take the *vector* spanning the distance from the origin (the number $1$) to $r_x$ in the divisor cuboid, and scale down this vector by factor $x$ to obtain $\sqrt[x]{r_x} = g$. To allow for a $y$ and $r_y$ in all possible cases of $r_x$, we must extend the divisor cuboid to all the primes. Then there are unconutably many points in the divisor cuboid in which the value equals $g$, since we can express $g$ as a real power of any single prime (or a product thereof). So it may be possible to find several such $n \in \mathbb{N}\:$, which are mutually prime and for which $g^n \in \mathbb{N}$. But I am not even fully convinced of this myself; let alone consider this a proof that could convince someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are coprime then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ax+by=1$. So if $g^x$ and $g^y$ are both natural numbers, we see that $g^{ax+by} = g$ is a rational number. So $g$ is rational. Say $g=p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.

Now we ahve $g^x = p^x/q^x = n$ where $n$ is a natural number. Therefore $q$ divides $p^x$. But since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, we must have that $q$ divides $p$, meaning that the only possibility is that $q=1$. This means that $g$ is a natural number.